# Finding relay coil voltage

Tags: relay, datasheet

I have a relay that I picked up from Radio Shack a while ago, and now I have a use for it, but I don't have the datasheet, and can't seem to find it online.

[image]

The top says GEO 3F-12V3

Below that it says 12VDC, which I'm hoping it's the coil voltage.

Near the bottom it says 15A 125VAC.

It is a SPDT relay, if that helps.

I just don't want to over volt the coil.

Comment: 3 seconds of googling: http://www.psrelay.com/images/3F%20CATALOG.pdf

Comment: 12VDC. It's the coil voltage.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Hmm, I guess I had seen that before a while back, but for some reason didn't think it was the right one. Sorry for wasting your time, but thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: The operating coil is rated at 12 V DC. The 15 A 125 V AC / 10 A 250 V AC block refers to the rating of the relay contacts. (It's somewhat harder to turn off a higher voltage so the current rating is lower to compensate for this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as the details kindly added as comments so far, this symbol on the relay (inside my added red circle) is the symbol for the coil:

[image: symbol inside red circle means relay coil]

So as you suspected, yes, this is telling you that the relay coil voltage is 12 VDC.

Answers to [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/240280/101852) previous question confirm the meaning of that symbol.